# Having problems adding a new data point inside and object in an array using for each

Tags: node.js

I'm having trouble trying to add a new entry into an existing array. I'm getting the data from mongoDB. If I change a value currently in the object/array with the same method is works fine. The documentation I've looked at seems to look the same as what I'm trying to do. Guess I'm missing something?

```
var managers = await User.find({
    accessLevel: [1, 2]
});

managers.forEach((manager) => {
    manager.newValue = 1;
    console.log(manager.newValue)
    console.log(manager)
})
```

Console output is:

```
1
{
  _id: ObjectId("62dc2a79c71582db37858ad4"),
  cashierId: 5,
  password: '#',
  firstName: '5',
  lastName: '5',
  accessLevel: 1,
  lastLogin: 2022-08-29T15:00:28.074Z,
  roles: null,
  nextTest: 2022-07-23T17:06:01.823Z,
  totalTest: 0,
  totalScore: 0,
  __v: 0
}
```

Expected output:

```
1
{
  _id: ObjectId("62dc2a79c71582db37858ad4"),
  cashierId: 5,
  password: '#',
  firstName: '5',
  lastName: '5',
  accessLevel: 1,
  lastLogin: 2022-08-29T15:00:28.074Z,
  roles: null,
  nextTest: 2022-07-23T17:06:01.823Z,
  totalTest: 0,
  totalScore: 0,
  newValue: 1,
  __v: 0
}
```

This if the code snippet with for loop.

```
var managers = await User.find({
    accessLevel: [1, 2] });
const dataMonth = await Check.find({})
const dataRequiredMonth = []



dataMonth.forEach((test) => {
    if (test.dateConducted.getMonth() === dayjs().month())
        dataRequiredMonth.push(test)
})

for (let i = 0; i < managers.length; i++) {
    managers[i].newValue = 1;
    console.log(managers[i].newValue)
    console.log(managers[i])
}
```

Comment: " If I change a currently value with the same method is works fine" its not clear to me what you are trying to say !

Comment: Sorry for that - to explain. If I for example set manager.totalTest = 1; this would indeed change the value I just seem to be unable to add a field/value.

Comment: the code seems perfectly ok to me... not quite sure what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

forEach(...) basically execute the callback for each element of specified array with element passed as an argument to callback.

this argument are local to function and thus any change made on that argument will not reflect on original elements

Try using simple for(...) loop it will resolve your issue.

> forEach() does not mutate the array on which it is called -Mozila

[for more information about forEach method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: I replaced this with a for loop and am getting the same issue.

Comment: share the code otherwise I cant figure out what's wrong